# OpenGL Shaders Don't Seem To Be Working

Tags: scala, opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I'm creating a program that uses *OpenGL 3.3*. I am using shaders in the program but they don't seem to have any effect on the triangle that I am displaying. They are loading and compiling fine though.

I am following a tutorial series [here](http://www.mbsoftworks.sk/index.php?page=tutorials&series=1).

#### Tutorial3.scala:

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat
import org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextAttribs
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils
import utils.Shader
import utils.ShaderProgram

class Tutorial3(WIDTH: Int, HEIGHT: Int, TITLE: String) extends utils.Disposable {

  /**
   * Create an Int VBO for our triangle
   */
  private var triangleVbo = 0
  /**
   * Create an Int VAO for our triangle
   */
  private var triangleVao = 0
  /**
   * Create a Float array for storing our triangle's vertices. 3 vertices, containing 3 values each (x,y,z)
   */
  private val triangleVertices: Array[Float] = new Array[Float](9)
  /**
   * Create a Float array for storing our trangle's colors
   */
  private val triangleColors: Array[Float] = new Array[Float](9)

  val vertexShader = new Shader()
  val fragmentShader = new Shader()
  val program = new ShaderProgram()

  setupOpenGl
  setupShapes

  while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
    loopCycle
    Display sync 60
    Display update
  }

  dispose

  private def setupOpenGl() {

     try {

       val pixelFormat = new PixelFormat
       val contextAttribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 3).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true)
       Display setDisplayMode new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
       Display setTitle TITLE
       Display create (pixelFormat, contextAttribs)

       GL11 glClearColor (1.0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f)

     } catch {

       case e:Throwable => e printStackTrace; sys exit 1

     }

  }

  private def setupShapes() {

    //Triangle
    triangleVertices(0) = -0.5f
    triangleVertices(1) = -0.5f
    triangleVertices(2) = 0f

    triangleVertices(3) = 0.5f
    triangleVertices(4) = -0.5f
    triangleVertices(5) = 0f

    triangleVertices(6) = 0f
    triangleVertices(7) = 0.5f
    triangleVertices(8) = 0f

    //Colors
    triangleColors(0) = 1.0f
    triangleColors(1) = 0f
    triangleColors(2) = 0f

    triangleColors(3) = 0f
    triangleColors(4) = 1.0f
    triangleColors(5) = 0f

    triangleColors(6) = 0f
    triangleColors(7) = 0f
    triangleColors(8) = 1.0f

    val triangleBuffer = BufferUtils createFloatBuffer triangleVertices.length

    triangleBuffer put triangleVertices

    triangleBuffer flip ()

    triangleVao = GL30 glGenVertexArrays ()
    GL30 glBindVertexArray triangleVao

    triangleVbo = GL15 glGenBuffers ()
    GL15 glBindBuffer (GL15 GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVbo)
    GL15 glBufferData (GL15 GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer, GL15 GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    GL20 glEnableVertexAttribArray 0
    GL20 glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL11 GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0)

    vertexShader loadShader ("vertex_shader_tutorial_3.glsl", GL20 GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    fragmentShader loadShader ("fragment_shader_tutorial_3.glsl", GL20 GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

    program createProgram ()
    program addShader vertexShader
    program addShader fragmentShader

    program linkProgram ()
    program useProgram ()

    GL15 glBindBuffer (GL15 GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
    GL30 glBindVertexArray (0)

  }

  private def loopCycle() {
    //Do Drawing / Logic
    GL11 glClear (GL11 GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    GL30 glBindVertexArray triangleVao
    GL20 glEnableVertexAttribArray 0

    GL11 glDrawArrays(GL11 GL_TRIANGLES, 0, triangleVertices length)

    GL20 glDisableVertexAttribArray 0
    GL30 glBindVertexArray 0
  }

  override def dispose() {
      GL20 glDisableVertexAttribArray 0

      GL15 glBindBuffer (GL15 GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
      GL15 glDeleteBuffers triangleVbo

      GL30 glBindVertexArray 0
      GL30 glDeleteVertexArrays triangleVao

      Display destroy
  }

}

object Tutorial3 {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    new Tutorial3(800, 600, "OpenGL 3.3 Tutorial 3")
  }

}
```

#### Shader.scala:

```
package utils

import java.io.File
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.FileReader
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20

class Shader extends Disposable {

  private var shader: Int = 0
  private var typ: Int = 0
  private var loaded: Boolean = false

  def loadShader(filename: String, typ: Int): Boolean = {

    val file: File = new File(System getProperty "user.dir", filename)

    if(!file.exists())
      false

    var line: String = ""
    val reader: BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))
    var shaderSource: String = ""

    while({line = reader.readLine(); line != null}) {
      shaderSource = shaderSource + line + "\n"
    }

    reader close

    this.shader = GL20 glCreateShader typ

    GL20 glShaderSource (this.shader, shaderSource)
    GL20 glCompileShader this.shader

    val status: Int = GL20 glGetShaderi(this.shader, GL20 GL_COMPILE_STATUS)

    if(status != 1)
      false

    this.typ = typ
    this.loaded = true

    true
  }

  def isLoaded(): Boolean = {
    this.loaded
  }

  def getShaderId(): Int = {
    this.shader
  }

  override def dispose() {
    GL20 glDeleteShader this.shader
  }

}
```

#### ShaderProgram.scala:

```
package utils

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20

class ShaderProgram extends Disposable {

  private var program: Int = 0
  private var linked: Int = 0

  def createProgram() {
    program = GL20 glCreateProgram
  }

  def useProgram() {
    GL20 glUseProgram this.program
  }

  def addShader(shader: Shader): Boolean = {
    GL20 glAttachShader(this.program, shader getShaderId)
    shader isLoaded
  }

  def linkProgram(): Boolean = {
    GL20 glLinkProgram this.program
    this.linked = GL20 glGetProgrami (this.program, GL20 GL_LINK_STATUS)
    this.linked != 0
  }

  def getProgramId(): Int = {
    this.program
  }

  override def dispose() {
    GL20 glDeleteProgram this.program
  }

}
```

#### Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 inColor;

smooth out vec3 theColor;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    theColor = inColor;
}
```

#### Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330

smooth in vec3 theColor;
out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
    outColor = vec4(theColor, 1.0);
}
```

What could be causing the shaders to not take effect?

Answer (score 1):

You only call

```
GL20 glEnableVertexAttribArray 0
```

But you use

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 inColor;
```

which leads me to think you should also call

```
GL20 glEnableVertexAttribArray 1
```

Unless I am seriously mistaken.

Comment: You will also need to call glVertexAttribPointer for location 1 like you did for location 0.